# Water clock in ancient time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

A Water clock used in ancient Greek is designed as a closed vessel with a small orifice O.The time is determined according to the level of the water in the vessel. What should the shape of the vessel be for the time scale to be uniform. find mathematical equation governing curve AOB.

[image: clock]

*question was asked to me by my friend*

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework-like questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we can assume the flow rate is low, so the flow is laminar, then the rate of water flow is given by the [Hagen-Poiseuille equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation):

$$ V = \frac{\pi r^4}{8\mu\ell} \Delta P $$

where $r$ is the radius of the neck, $\ell$ is the length of the neck and $\mu$ is the viscosity. The pressure different, $\Delta P$, is given by:

$$ \Delta P = \rho g h $$

where $\rho$ is the density of the liquid and $h$ is the height of liquid above the neck.

So for any given clock the flow rate is proportional to $h$. As the liquid level drops, i.e. $h$ decreases, the flow rate will fall. For the time scale to be linear you need to adjust the cross sectional area so the change in $h$ with time remains constant. Hopefully this should be enough clues for you to take it from here.